# vb.net - delete folder then create it, but not exists

Tags: vb.net, io

In vs2010, there is a `vb.net` project, I need to clean a folder before use it,
what I did is remote the folder, then create it again.
but the problem is ,it is removed but not created again.

I think maybe .net did some optimization. So how can I fix that?

Here is the code:

```
    ' delete folder
    If IO.Directory.Exists(exportBaseFolder) = True Then
        IO.Directory.Delete(exportBaseFolder, True)
    End If

    ' create folder
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(exportBaseFolder)
```

Comment: If the folder has any substantial files to it, the delete process is still going on while your trying to create it.

Comment: @OneFineDay Ok, so how do I fix that?

Comment: One way is with an empty while loop that exits when the directory no longer exists.  Then create it.

Comment: @tinstaafl That seems not very good...

Comment: No, but then deleting a directory and all files and subdirectories just to create and empty one is an unusual situation. You could  rename the directory then delete it.  While it's deleting you can create the new one.

Comment: @tinstaafl Thx, that's a good idea that I could use.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Directory.GetFiles and foreach file, file.delete. Then delete the folder.  Then if not folder exists, create it.